# Multiprocessing with GUI, python

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

Right now I am working on a GUI application which will essentially run 4 processes concurrently/ in parallel.

I have been unable to achieve multiprocessing with the tkinter application as it always ended in "can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects" and "EOFError: Ran out of input".

Essentially it is meant to run 4 process while updating its GUI. as of right now i am testing it with 2 process just to ensure that it is working.

Code Below:

```
import tkinter
import multiprocessing as mp
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from CV2_Frame_Extraction import *
from Color_Extractor_CT import *
from graph import *



customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"



class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    btn_list = []
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #Window Configuration
        self.title("Plasma Analysis")
        self.geometry("1100x580")

        #Layout Configuration
        #if needed later
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        #Side Bar
        self.sb_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self,width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sb_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=4,sticky="nsew")
        self.sb_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4,weight=1)

        self.sb_new = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sb_frame, text="Add Video",command=self.openfile,corner_radius=2)
        self.sb_new.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=20)


        self.btn_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.sb_frame,width=140,height=400,corner_radius=0,fg_color="transparent",border_width=5)
        self.btn_frame.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=3)
    
        self.bf_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.btn_frame,text="Analysis", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"),fg_color="transparent")
        self.bf_label.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.appearance_mode_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sb_frame, text="Appearance Mode:", anchor="w")
        self.appearance_mode_label.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.sb_frame, values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],
                                                                   command=self.change_appearance_mode_event)
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))
        self.scaling_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sb_frame, text="UI Scaling:", anchor="w")
        self.scaling_label.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.scaling_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.sb_frame, values=["80%", "90%", "100%", "110%", "120%"],
                                                           command=self.change_scaling_event)
        self.scaling_optionemenu.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 20))


        #Creating Main Panel
        self.main_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self,width=950,corner_radius=0,fg_color='transparent')
        self.main_frame.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=4,columnspan=4,sticky="nsew")
   
        self.tab_a1 = customtkinter.CTkTabview(self.main_frame,width=400,height=250,segmented_button_selected_color='gray',border_width=5)
        self.tab_a1.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=(30,50),pady=(15,15),sticky="nsew")
        self.tab_a1.grid_propagate(False)
        self.tab_a1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0,uniform=1)
        self.tab_a1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1,uniform=1)
        self.tab_a1.add("Color")

        self.tab_a2 = customtkinter.CTkTabview(self.main_frame,width=400,height=250,segmented_button_selected_color='gray',border_width=5)
        self.tab_a2.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=(0,50),pady=(15,15),sticky="nsew")
        self.tab_a2.add("Luminosity")

        self.tab_a3 = customtkinter.CTkTabview(self.main_frame,width=400,height=250,segmented_button_selected_color='gray',border_width=5)
        self.tab_a3.grid(row=1,column=0, padx=(30,50),pady=(15,15),sticky="nsew")
        self.tab_a3.add("Motion")

        self.tab_a4 = customtkinter.CTkTabview(self.main_frame,width=400,height=250,segmented_button_selected_color='gray',border_width=5)
        self.tab_a4.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=(0,50),pady=(15,15),sticky="nsew")
        self.tab_a4.add("Trend")


    def change_appearance_mode_event(self, new_appearance_mode: str):
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)

    def change_scaling_event(self, new_scaling: str):
        new_scaling_float = int(new_scaling.replace("%", "")) / 100
        customtkinter.set_widget_scaling(new_scaling_float)

    def openfile(self):     
        decision = filedialog.askopenfilename().split('/')
        name = decision[len(decision)-1].split('.')[0]

        p1 = mp.Process(target=self.loading, args=())
        p2 = mp.Process(target=self.getGraph, args=(decision,))

        self.btn_list.append(customtkinter.CTkButton(self.btn_frame,text=name))     
        for x,btn in enumerate(self.btn_list):
            btn.grid(row=x+1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

        p1.start()
        #p2.start()

    def loading(self):
        lbl_load = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.tab_a2.tab('Luminosity'),text="Loading ...",font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        lbl_load1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.tab_a3.tab('Motion'),text="Loading ...",font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        lbl_load2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.tab_a4.tab('Trend'),text="Loading ...",font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        lbl_load.pack(side=tkinter.TOP,fill=tkinter.BOTH,expand=True,anchor='center')
        lbl_load1.pack(side=tkinter.TOP,fill=tkinter.BOTH,expand=True,anchor='center')
        lbl_load2.pack(side=tkinter.TOP,fill=tkinter.BOTH,expand=True,anchor='center')

        self.update()


    def getGraph(self,decision):
        frame_extraction('\\'.join(decision))

        colors = ["Red","Green","Blue"]
        red = []
        green = []
        blue = []

        files = os.listdir('Frames')
        sorted_files = [file.replace('f_','') for file in files]
        sorted_files = sorted(sorted_files, key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]))

        for frame in sorted_files:          
            rgb = color_extraction(f'Frames/f_{frame}')
            r,g,b = rgb[0]
            red.append(r)
            green.append(g)
            blue.append(b)
            print(f'Frame: {frame} RGB:{rgb[0]}')


        frames = [(int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]))*20 for x in sorted_files]
        figs = generate_graph(red,green,blue,frames)

        self.tab_a1.delete("Color")

        for idx,f in enumerate(figs):
            self.tab_a1.add(colors[idx])
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,self.tab_a1.tab(colors[idx]))
            f.tight_layout()
            canvas.draw()           
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP,fill=tkinter.BOTH,expand=True,anchor='center')

        self.tab_a1.configure(fg_color="White")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: GUI applications can only run in a single thread in a single process, you cannot have two threads or applications controlling 1 GUI, if you want to use multiprocessing to speed up some things, then these things must not relate to GUI, and only do simple things like opening a file and reading some data from it, and you need the function that  you call in the other process to not be part of the GUI, (a separate function outside of class, or in a class that doesn't inherit or contain any GUI objects), using multiprocessing inside a GUI application is equivalent to running 2 applications are once.

Comment: swap any `multiprocessing.Process` with `threading.Thread` and you'll get what you expect, but it still won't be safe and you might run into errors as you shouldn't be doing any parallelization in a GUI applicaiton, but your code will work most of the time. avoid multiprocessing unless you really know what you are doing, your "tasks" are not suitable for multiprocessing, and not exactly suitable for threading either.